# UML diagram: How to show interface that is implemented by most of the Classes in my class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have a interface like:

```
public interface MyEntity {

    //HIbernate version
    public long getOptLock();

    //these method are used to keep track of Last modified timestamp 
    public void update();

    public void persist();

}
```

Which is implemented  by most of the classes in my object model. Now, i know how to show a [interface realisation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cimplement.html) in a Class diagram.

The problem is since this particular interface is implemented by most of the classes it is making the class diagram cluttered. Is there a altenative way to show interface realisation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The alternative way is to use the **lollipop notation**, right above every class that implements the interface:

See this [image](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC267834.png) from msdn website.

For the full article see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/dd409416.aspx#Inheritance).

Comment: Okay thanks. I was under impression that lollipop notation was only for marker interface. This helps a lot.